# oracle apex replace function javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am having trouble replacing a comma with a colon in one of the variables in a dynamic action javascript code.

I tried the following

```
val = replace(val, ",", ":");
```

but got an error `replace is not defined`

I also tried

```
val = val.replace(",",":");
```

but it also errored out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I realized that `val` was an array of values, so i used `Join` to replace commas with colons and make it into a string:

val.Join(":");

worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This will replace only the first occurrance of `,`. You should use a regular expression instead of a string for the first argument of the function.

```
 val = val.replace(/,/g, ":")
```

Comment: this gives me an error `val.replace is not a function`

Comment: Is `val` a string?